# Make maven use the current code and not the installed version when compiling child projects

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project P that consists of several submodules s1,s2... To make this work, I have the following directory structure:

```
P
|_pom.xml
|_s1
  |_pom.xml
|_..
|_sN
  |_pom.xml
```

In the parent `pom.xml`, I have a normal maven setup:

```
<project xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>P</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>P</name>
  <modules>
    <module>s1</module>
    <module>s2</module>
    <!-- ... -->
    <module>sN</module>
  </modules>
  <!-- Repos and dependencies go here -->
</project>
```

And, for each of the child projects, a `pom.xml` similar to this one:

```
<project xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>s1</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Additionally, in the project, I have some inter-module dependencies, so for example s4 might require s1 s2 and s5. In order to make this work, I list the submodules as depencencies of other submodules, so for example, in s4's `pom.xml` I would have:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>s1</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

The problem with this setup is that, whenever I compile one of the submodule projects, changes in the other submodules are not seen unless they have been previously installed with `mvn install`. That makes sense, since I'm listing the inter-module dependencies with a specific version, and maven goes to the local repository in the `.m2` folder to find them.

Is there a way I can tell maven that I'm in charge of all these projects and that it should recursively go and compile other dependent submodules whenever there are changes?

Comment: TL;DR: It can't be done, you must rebuild the parent project, this was not directly answered in the "duplicate" question, so I'll leave this comment for anyone interested.

Comment: Perhaps not a complete answer to your question, but the `-amd` flag makes maven also build the dependencies of the submodule you're building. If that is insufficient, you could also use the `-pl` (`--projects`) flag to explicitly specify a list of submodules to build like `mvn <goals> -pl :s1,:s2,:s5` (notice the colon before the submodule name)