# How do I get maven to pick up my local jar in repositories?

Tags: java, maven

I am writing a package (`PACK-A`) that is consumed by another (`PACK-B`). For local development I want to use a local jar that is produced from `PACK-A` and use it in `PACK-B`.

The workflow would be

1. cd `PACK-A`; `mvn clean; mvn package`
2. cd `PACK-B`; `mvn clean; mvn package` (but pulls in the local `PACK-A` jar file)

I thought the way to do it was through the `<repositories />` tag in the `pom.xml` file so my `POM.xml` file looks like this (lots taken out for brevity):

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.team</groupId>
  <artifactId>PACK-B</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  
  <dependencies>
      <groupId>com.company.team</groupId>
      <artifactId>service-name</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.0-master+17</version>
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>service-name</id>
      <url>file:///Users/username/Projects/service-name/target</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

`file:///Users/username/Projects/service-name/target` is the directory that compiles (`mvn package`) the `service.jar`.

It isn't picking it up and I've confirmed it using a decompiler. How do I get maven to use my local jar in the service that I compiled? Or is my `<url>` directory written out incorrectly?

Also, I've confirmed, via the decompiler, that the service does compile with my changes. It just isn't picked up by my consumer.

Comment: A repository must follow the structure of a maven repository, and the `target` directory doesn't. Use `mvn install` to install the library in your local repository instead, and remove the `repositories` block from your pom.xml

Comment: Are you looking for `mvn install`?

Comment: Interesting, I've tried using `mvn install` for local jars and I wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

> For local development I want to use a local jar that is produced from PACK-A and use it in PACK-B.

To achieve this, you "only need":

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company.team</groupId>
  <artifactId>PACK-B</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>   
      <groupId>com.company.team</groupId>
      <artifactId>PACK-A</artifactId>
      <!-- same version, or which ever suits you -->
      <version>${project.version}</version> 
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And to run `mvn install` (which additionally to `package` installs the artifact into the local repository).

See also: [How to build dependent project when building a module in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25480598/592355)
and [What does mvn install in maven exactly do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10533828/592355)

It is a "complex field" (multi-module...), but the thing You are trying to achieve is really simple/101.